Median lines in ggplot boxplot for individual categories/subgroups
Is there a way of having multiple median lines within a boxplot for individual subgroups? Probably not clear from the code but I have jitters to show all datapoints of four "methods" and in addition would like a line corresponding to each method withing the boxplot. I have tried stat_summary but this just connects the medians using a line.
ggplot(df, aes(x = IS, y = value))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(group=IS), outliers = FALSE)+
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2)+
  geom_jitter(aes(shape=Type, colour = Type), position = position_jitter(width=0.2))+
  scale_shape_manual(values = box_shapes)+
  scale_color_manual(values= box_cols)+
  theme_minimal()+
  labs(x = "IS", y = "Concentration")+
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.ticks.y = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text = element_text(face = "bold"))


It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.
